# PHP values update from $_POST

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a shopping cart.

I have this sample form:

```
<form action="./post.php" method="POST">
product id: <input type="text" name="prod" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

I've done the field visible to test the script.

PHP Code

```
<?php
$prods=$_POST['prod'];
for($i=0; $i < count($prods); $i++){
$new=$prods[$i];
echo $new;
}
?>
```

If I enter a first value to I save it in a new `$_POST['prod']`. Then, if I go back to the form and enter a second one, I'd like to update the array, so that will contain those 2 values.

How can I do that? I have tried all day to do it, but no result, so you're my last chance.

Comment: You should really add the PHP code you're using, and not just the form definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of your data is lost with each new HTTP request as HTML/PHP is stateless. To maintain state you would need to use [sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

**edit**

```
<?php
session_start();                      // start session
$prods=$_POST['prod'];
if (!isset($_SESSION['products'])) {  // check if session var exists
    $_SESSION['products'] = array();  // create session variable as an array
}
$_SESSION['products'][] = $prod;      // add new product

// do other stuff
?>
```

Comment: I also tried to use sessions. I saved the first value, but no idea how to add the second one comma separated.

Comment: Can't help you with that without seeing your code. As a new question showing the code you wrote and we'll be happy to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could append the new submission to an array you store in $_SESSION.

```
$_SESSION['current_products'][] = $_POST['prod'];
```

That will append each POSTed product to an array in the SESSION variable. That's easier than storing them comma-separated -- to retrieve them in a comma-separated fashion, just use `implode`:

```
$products = implode(",",$_SESSION['current_products']);
```

Hope this helps.